# Access from multiple source files to one struct array

Tags: c++

I tried to upgrade my "working code" with a new function. For this I tried to outsource some functionality into separate files.

At the moment I'm not sure what to do and I can't find a solution for the problem.
The code below is only a little part of the code, but I hope it is enough to explain what is going wrong.

I need a global struct array as shown below in global_def.
I need access to the same data field from different files (functions).

If I do it in this way, I get the following error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct resultFieldColor
   setFieldColor(fieldNr , resultFieldColorArray[fieldNr].resultHue , resultFieldColorArray[fieldNr].resultSaturation, resultFieldColorArray[fieldNr].reusltBrightness , ledCounter)
```

global_def.h

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_DEF_H
#define GLOBAL_DEF_H
        
struct resultFieldColor;
extern resultFieldColor resultFieldColorArray[];
```

global_def.cpp

```
struct resultFieldColor
{
    byte resultHue = 0;
    byte resultSaturation = 0;
    byte reusltBrightness = 0;
};

resultFieldColor resultFieldColorArray[5];
```

colorFuncOne.cpp

```
#include <GLOBAL_DEF.h>
#include <LED_control.h>

setFieldColor(fieldNr , resultFieldColorArray[fieldNr].resultHue , resultFieldColorArray[fieldNr].resultSaturation, resultFieldColorArray[fieldNr].reusltBrightness , ledCounter);
```

colorFuncTwo.cpp

```
#include <GLOBAL_DEF.h>
#include <LED_control.h>

setFieldColor(fieldNr , resultFieldColorArray[fieldNr].resultHue , resultFieldColorArray[fieldNr].resultSaturation, resultFieldColorArray[fieldNr].reusltBrightness , ledCounter);
```

Comment: The `resultFieldColor` structure definition needs to be in the header for all users of `resultFieldColorArray` to know what members are in the elements of the array.

Comment: Side note: Since you're heading in the direction of global variables shared across multiple files, understand, respect, and fear [the Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at our [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with special attention to the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is not just for our convenience; it is a vital coding skill.

Comment: Your error message mentions `ergebnisFeldFarbe`, but this identifier does not appear in your code. I assume you translated your identifiers for our benefit? That is good, but you should also update the error message. A good general procedure to follow is to first create a [mre] (MRE) that demonstrates the issue. Second, copy the MRE -- exactly as it appears in your question -- and compile that code. Copy the resulting error message into your question. This ensures that the code actually reproduces the issue, and it ensures that the error message matches the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The struct's layout has to be included in the header file.

```
struct ResultFieldColor {
  byte resultHue = 0;
  byte resultSaturation = 0;
  byte resultBrightness = 0;
};
```

You may have heard people say not to do this. What they meant was that function implementations shouldn't be in the header, so if you have a function `foo`, the header should look like

```
void foo(int x);
```

and the C++ file should have the body, as

```
void foo(int x) {
  // Look at me, I'm a function ^.^
}
```

But structs/classes need to have their layout available in the header. That includes any function declarations (though not their definitions), any template functions (definitions *and* declarations), and any instance variables.

Note that there are [some tricks](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) to work around this, but they tend to be complicated and carry runtime implications, so it's best to simply include the variables in the header file generally.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem, sometimes it is that easy if you know what to do.